# android: OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener for all activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in my main activity:

```
private SharedPreferences settings;
private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
            MainActivity.this.refreshDisplay(null);
        }
    };
    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
}
public void refreshDisplay(View view){
    //code
}
```

this way I should implement this listener inside all of my activities. because of I've menu in my action bar called settings. I want to know Is there any generic way(defining that listener inside a class and call it in other activities) to do that?
**Thanks in advanced.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a `SharedPrefsListenerActivity` Class which extends `Activity`.
2. Add the listener inside `SharedPrefsListenerActivity`.
3. Make sure all other activities extend `SharedPrefsListenerActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create BaseActivity implementing the listener (OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener())
2. Use BaseActivity (YourActivity extends BaseActivity)